# Do my prejudices get "fulfilled"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

When reality agrees with my prejudices, they get __. What's the right word?

For example: "I had long been prejudiced against city-dwellers as wayward and spendthrift; and when I saw the lust and lucre of New Delhi, my prejudices were __."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had long been prejudiced against city-dwellers as wayward and spendthrift; and when I saw the lust and lucre of New Delhi, my prejudices were . . .

1) justified
2) confirmed

Prejudices are not 'fulfilled', because a prejudice is an opinion.

I had long been prejudiced against city-dwellers as wayward and spendthrift; and when I saw the lust and lucre of New Delhi, I saw that my prejudices were  ...

1) valid
2) reasonable
3) not unfounded/baseless

Comment: @mplungjan It's quite not so.

Comment: @mplung: Chances are that he didn't. Besides the answers being posted just 40 seconds apart, that simply doesn't happen on this kind of site.

Comment: No, I did not copy it. I got the alert that "1 more answer has been posted" just before I was about to hit my POST button.

Comment: calm down ladies

Comment: someone just had their prejudices confirmed

Answer (score 3):

Your prejudices were *reinforced* or *vindicated*.

Comment: I think 'reinforced' is a better word in this context than 'vindicated'.

Comment: It depends on what you want to say. To say that your prejudices were *reinforced* is neutral or a bit negative toward the content of those prejudices. To say that they are *vindicated* is to take an opinionated stance in support of those prejudices: it says they were proven correct.

Answer (score 2):

- Affirmed
- Confirmed

Comment: I don't think *affirm* is appropriate here because it is something a person does: *state emphatically or publicly*

Comment: confirmed sounds better

Answer (score 1):

- Justified?

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed for a rather inflexible answer; justified implying a slightly less definite conclusion; appropriate suggesting they were not unfounded; reinforced, bolstered, supported, strengthened implying they were added to; correct if you want to appear more reactionary.  Cobmbinations of words may fit better - sadly true, not unfounded, not without cause etc etc.